# Solving $f'''+\frac{n+1}{2}ff''-nf'^2+n=0$ with $n=e^\pi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

How do I solve

$$f'''+\frac{n+1}{2}ff''-nf'^2+n=0$$

with $n=e^\pi$ or arbitrary $n$?

This equation occurs in my model for the time evolution of the value of Bitcoin.

Comment: Two trivial solutions: $f(t) = c+t$, $f(t) = c-t$, where $c$ is any constant.

Comment: What is the independent variable?

Comment: @GEdgar Nice find!

Comment: @doraemonpaul $t$

Comment: Your equation is similar to the Falkner–Skan equation in fluid mechanics. With $n=0$ you obtain the Blasius equation. I would suggest to read some papers about them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a third order non-linear autonomous ODE. It can be reduced to a second order non-linear ODE. I think that it cannot be analytically solved in the general case with a finite number of elementary and/or current referenced special functions.!
$$\text{Change of notation for clarity: $f(x)\equiv y(x)$}\\\,\\
\dfrac{\mathrm d^3y}{\mathrm dx^3}+\dfrac{n+1}{2}y\dfrac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx}-n\left(\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2+n=0\\\,\\
\text{Let : }\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=F(y)\quad\to\quad\dfrac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}=\dfrac{\mathrm dF}{\mathrm dy}\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=F\dfrac{\mathrm dF}{\mathrm dy}\\\,\\
\dfrac{\mathrm d^3y}{\mathrm dx^3}=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\left(\dfrac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}\right)\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\left(F\dfrac{\mathrm dF}{\mathrm dy}\right)F=F^2\dfrac{\mathrm d^2F}{\mathrm dy^2}+F\left(\dfrac{\mathrm dF}{\mathrm dy}\right)^2\\\,\\
F^2\dfrac{\mathrm d^2F}{\mathrm dy^2}+F\left(\dfrac{\mathrm dF}{\mathrm dy}\right)^2+\dfrac{n+1}{2}yF\dfrac{\mathrm dF}{\mathrm dy}-nF^2+n=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [How do you solve this kind of third order ODE? (non-linear Blasius equation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195903),

Let $u=(f')^2$ ,

Then $\pm\dfrac{\sqrt u}{2}\dfrac{d^2u}{df^2}+\dfrac{n+1}{4}f\dfrac{du}{df}-nu+n=0$